# Normal distribution test sample

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to use R to find the probability that 2 randomly selected out of 10 would be within a certain range. I am not sure if I am doing it right. This is with a normal distribution.

```
prob <- pnorm(4200, mean=3100, sd=600)-pnorm(2800, mean=3100, sd=600)
dbinom(2, size =10, p=prob, log=FALSE)
```

I'm not sure if I might be overthinking it and that the probability should just be the following because I am only trying to 'probability that two of the ten' being within the range.

`pnorm(4200, mean=3100, sd=600)-pnorm(2800, mean=3100, sd=600)`

Comment: Can you give more details about the probability you're trying to find? Is the question "What is the probability at least 2 out of the 10 points are within a certain distance of each other", or "at least 2 out of the 10 points are between X and Y", or one of those but with "exactly 2...". Or is the question something else?  Are you looking for an exact solution or is a simulation approximation ok?

Comment: The question is "What is the probability that two of the ten items weigh between 3100 and 4200" They don't elaborate any more on it which has me confused. I have been told there will be no further elaboration at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to @DavidLuke does not seem to be consistent with your original Question. What happened to 2800?

Suppose the full question is, "Given that ten observations are taken at random
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=3100,\sigma=600),$ what is the probability that *exactly* two of the ten lie in the interval $(2800, 4200)?$"  Then you might answer in R as
follows:

```
p = diff(pnorm(c(2800, 4200), 3100, 600));  p
[1] 0.658086
dbinom(2, 10, p)
[1] 0.0036401
```

For "*at least* two of the ten," I get  $0.9995579$ from a slightly different
binomial computation.